# Canvas arcTo() method

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am playing with HTML5 canvas , my book says that

> latest browser supports arcTo method and it has capabilities to remove
>   arc() function .

**My question is how?**

Also I am confused with this example of arcTo , why its getting formed in this way can someone explain

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" ></canvas>
    
    <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var drawScreen = function(){
       context.moveTo(0,0);
       context.lineTo(100,200); 
       context.arcTo(350,350,100,100,20);
       context.stroke();
      }
      
      drawScreen();
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here is the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arcTo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some pseudocode explaining how the JavaScript code you posted works:

```
1) Get the canvas, and store it to variable 'canvas'
2) Get the 2d context of 'canvas', and store it to variable 'context'

3) Initialize a function, 'drawScreen', that takes no arguments, but runs the following instructions:
   a) Move the pen to (0,0) on the canvas.
   b) Draw a line from the pen's current position to (100, 100)
   c) Draw an arc with a tangent line that passes through (350, 350) and the current pen position, and another tangent line that passes through (350, 350) and (100, 100), around a circle with radius 20.
   d) Push the updated canvas to the screen.
4) Run the function 'drawScreen'
```

Believe it or not, you can use `arcTo` or a combination of other commands to do exactly the same thing `arc` does, albeit with more work, and there are numerous examples of this online.